# Espresso Test Recorder missing from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-espresso-recorder

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.1 and couldn't find the Espresso Test Recorder button. I checked with my friends they have the same Android Studio version as mine but they have the button in Run->Espresso Test Recorder button.

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSqiB.png)

Answer (score 21):

Make sure that the Test Recorder Plugin is enabled.

Go to File → Settings → Plugins

[image].

Find the *Test Recorder* plugin in the list. Enable the checkbox next to it and click OK.

The Espresso Test Recorder button should then be available from the Run menu as expected.

Comment: The button isn't there out of the box in 2020 for me. Run -> "Record Espresso Test" does the trick.